# WorkLight 6.2 BusyIndicator dynamic sizing causes increase in box height

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

While increasing the size of WL.BusyIndicator as shown below, the height of the box also increases giving it a wierd look. Is it possible to handle the height and width of the box, so that i can have a nicer look.

```
busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator('content', 
            { text: "Initiating registration", bounceAnimation: true, fullScreen: false,  
                textColor: "white", opacity: 0.5, strokeOpacity: 0.25, boxLength: 200
            });
busyIndicator.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The ability to increase only the *height* of the Worklight-generated busy indicator is not available.

You can:

- [Submit a feature request](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/) to be considered for future releases
- And/or create your own/find online a library that does this extended customizability (basically - create your own busy indicator) in native code, and trigger in your app [by implementing it as a Cordova plug-in](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_native_to_hybrid)
- And/or create your own/find online a JavaScript-based busy indicator implementation and trigger in your app using JS...